# DockerコンテナからホストPCの内蔵カメラを用いた撮影がしたい

Tags: python, docker

DockerでPCカメラ撮影のpythonプログラムを実行すると、PCカメラが起動して撮影することが出来ます。
以下がソースコードです。

```
import cv2
import os
def save_frame_camera_key(device_num=0, dir_path='.', basename = 'camera_capture', ext='jpg', delay=1, window_name='frame'):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device_num)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        return
    os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)
    base_path = os.path.join(dir_path, basename)
    n = 0
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('c'):
            cv2.imwrite('{}_{}.{}'.format(base_path, n, ext), frame)
            n += 1
        elif key == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(window_name)
save_frame_camera_key(0, 'data/temp', 'camera_capture')
```

しかし実行すると以下のエラー文が出てきます。

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
```

調べてみると、cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device_num)の()内を0から-1にすると解決するということをネット記事で見つけたので修正して実行してみたら、

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device
```

という違うエラーが出てきました。

何か良い解決方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.3
WORKDIR /app
COPY cam.py /app/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim && apt-get install -y curl
RUN pip install blockext==0.1.0 opencv-python==4.1.1.26
EXPOSE 4226
```

### 環境

ホストOSはwindows10HomeでDockerToolboxを使っています。
カメラはノートPCに内蔵されているカメラです。
コンテナ内のOSはLinuxです。(おそらく)

Comment: コンテナ上のOSからホストに接続されたカメラを参照して、という事でしょうか。念のため、コンテナとホストのOSの種類等の情報と、カメラも何で接続しているか(USB or 内蔵？)辺りの情報もあると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ホストOSはwindows10HomeでDockerToolboxを使っています。カメラはノートPCに内蔵されているカメラです。コンテナの情報で必要なのはなんでしょうか？

Comment: コンテナの OS 情報が欲しいです。本文に追記してくださいますでしょうか。

Comment: コンテナを動かしているwindowsがOSではないのでしょうか？？コンテナのOSの調べ方教えていただきたいです。

Comment: コンテナの中でもなんらかのOSが動いており、ホストOSと同じとは限りません。 / Dockerfile を見る限りは Debian (Linux) でしょう。

Comment: 環境が違うようなので参考になるか不明ですが、この辺の記事を参照してみては？ [Docker access to webcam from Windows 10](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/7uj4m8/docker_access_to_webcam_from_windows_10/), [Connect the webcam to Docker on Mac or Windows](https://medium.com/@jijupax/connect-the-webcam-to-docker-on-mac-or-windows-51d894c44468), [Windows環境でDockerコンテナにUSBウェブカメラを認識させてみる](https://www.unitrust.co.jp/7117), [Docker上でWebカメラ(UVC)を使う方法](https://qiita.com/Eliza_wb/items/6ac73679b6d2a2316a2b), [GPUユーザーは、すぐにdockerからsingularityに切り替えるべきだと思った８つのこと](https://www.ecomottblog.com/?p=3903)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker for winのissueでは、内蔵カメラをコンテナから使用する事は不可能としています
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2201

コメントにもある通り、usb経由のカメラであればいくつか方法はあると思います。
例えば：https://medium.com/@jijupax/connect-the-webcam-to-docker-on-mac-or-windows-51d894c44468